# Regression in R - Regression line with wrong intercept

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have a question regarding a regression which i did in R-Studio. My statistical output say its an **intercept with the y-axis "-196"**

but when i display the line with

```
geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~x)
```

the intercept and the line cant be right. I also checked the dataframe and it looks fine.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong here?

Thx so much for your help

Dataframe:

[.csv Dataframe](https://easyupload.io/oqwwy0)

Full code:

```
 df_final %>%
  filter(!is.na(case_per_million), !is.na(kof)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(kof, case_per_million, fill = region)) +
  geom_point(color = "white",
             shape = 21, alpha = 0.7, size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, na.rm = TRUE, fullrange = TRUE,
              aes(group = 1), color = "steelblue",
              show.legend = FALSE,
              se = FALSE) +
  theme_ipsum_ps(grid = "XY",
                 axis = TRUE,
                 ticks = TRUE,
                 axis_col = "grey20") +
  labs(x = "KOF Globalisation Index (in 2017)",
       y = "COVID-19 Fälle pro 100.000 Einwohner (log)",
       title = "COVID-19 Fälle pro 100.000 Einwohner vs KOF Globalisation Index" ) +
  scale_y_log10(label = function(x) scales::comma(x, accuracy = 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Region",
                    values = c("#98064A",
                               "#2D8587",
                               "#4C5C78",
                               "#E04E4B",
                               "#662C68",
                               "#932834")) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(linetype = "dashed"),
        legend.position = c(1,0),
        legend.justification = c(1,0))
```

and for the Output i used:

```
    reg2 <- lm(case_per_million ~ kof,
           data = df_final)
summary(reg2)
```

Comment: Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. It's hard to say without access to your data. You can [edit] your question to paste the output of the R commands `dput(y)` and `dput(x)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I totally forgot.

Comment: Now I can see the issue: You're log transforming the Y axis, which applies to the `lm()` call `ggplot()` does as well I think. You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275288/r-log-transform-linear-fit-of-geom-smooth instructive

Comment: Thank you!!!! I don’t know, how I missed that. Sorry for the rough start:/

Comment: No worries! We live and learn. Glad we found the source of your troubles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I think you added a log scale to your y-axis, which means that you end up fitting a log-linear regression instead of a linear regression.

In a clean R session, loading your data:

```
m1 <- lm(case_per_million ~ kof, data=df_reg)
coef(m1)
library(ggplot2)
gg0 <- ggplot(df_reg, aes(kof, case_per_million)) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm",fullrange=TRUE) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,NA)) +
    geom_point()
gg1 <- gg0 + scale_y_log10()
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(gg0,gg1)
```

[image]

Comment: in fact: This looks perfect. Unfortunately I still cannot find my error in my code:/

Comment: Wow thank you!!  How did I miss that.  So dumb. You truly saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

your x and y axis could be flipped. Can't answer for sure though without knowing the data that went into it.

try this plot should make more sense now

```
plot (df$case_per_million ~ df$kof)
abline(lm(df$case_per_million ~ df$kof))
```

Comment: unfortunately no, this was also my first idea

Comment: plot (df$case_per_million ~ df$kof)                            abline(lm(df$case_per_million ~ df$kof))