# R: plotting geom_line() of lm() prediction values and geometric smooth do not coincide

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I have the following data

```
df <- data.frame(x= c(0,1,10,100,1000,0,1, 10,100,1000,0,1,10,100,1000), 
                 y=c(7,15,135,1132,6459,-3,11,127,1120,6249,-5,13,126,1208,6208))
```

After making a linear model using the data, I used the model to predict y values from know x values. Stored the predicted y values in a data frame "pred.fits"

```
fit <- lm(data = df, y ~ x)

pred.fits <- expand.grid(x=seq(1, 2000, length=2001))

pm <- predict(fit, newdata=pred.fits, interval="confidence")

pred.fits$py <- pm[,1]
```

I plot the data and use both geom_smooth() and geom_line(), they seem to be quite coincident.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, size=1.5) +
       geom_line(data=pred.fits, aes(x=x, y=py), size=.2)
```

[image]

However, when I plot the same data, with setting the axes in log scale the two regressions differs drastically.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, size=1.5) +
       geom_line(data=pred.fits, aes(x=x, y=py), size=.2) + 
       scale_x_log10() + 
       scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

After @Duck pointed me to correct direction, I was able to get it right. The issue was, I wanted the data to be untransformed, but the axes transformed to log10 scale. This is how I was able to do it.

```
df2 <- df[df$x>=1,] # remove annoying warning msgs.

fit2 <- lm(data = df2, log10(y) ~ log10(x))

pred.fits2 <- expand.grid(x=seq(10^0, 10^3  , length=200))

pm2 <- predict(fit2, newdata=pred.fits2, interval="confidence")

pred.fits2$py <-  10^pm2[,1] # convert the predicted y values to linear scale

ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, size=1.5) +
geom_line(data=pred.fits2, aes(x=x, y=py), size=1.5, linetype = "longdash") + 
scale_x_log10() +
scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Check this answer, also in your data there are negative values and zeroes that might be affecting the computing of smoothing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275288/r-log-transform-linear-fit-of-geom-smooth

Comment: adding to what @Duck said (totally correct that negative and 0 are issues)- you also will not get the same results because in your 2nd figure you are estimating a regression on log transformed data and plotting the *results* of a linear regression into log space, which are not equal. if it was then we would simply run a regression and log transform the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can be useful for your understanding (Thanks to @BWilliams for the valious comment). You want x and y in log scale so if mixing a linear model with different scales can mess everything. If you want to see similar scales it is better if you train a different model with log variables and then plot it also using the proper values. Here an approach where we build a log-log model and then plot (data values as ones or negative have been isolated in a new dataframe `df2`). Here the code:

First linear model:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(x= c(0,1,10,100,1000,0,1, 10,100,1000,0,1,10,100,1000), 
                 y=c(7,15,135,1132,6459,-3,11,127,1120,6249,-5,13,126,1208,6208))

#Model 1 all obs
fit <- lm(data = df, y ~ x)
pred.fits <- expand.grid(x=seq(1, 2000, length=2001))
pm <- predict(fit, newdata=pred.fits, interval="confidence")
pred.fits$py <- pm[,1]
#Plot 1
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, size=1.5) +
  geom_line(data=pred.fits, aes(x=x, y=py), size=.2)
```

Output:

[image]

Now the sketch for log variables, notice how we use `log()` across main variables and also how the model is build:

```
#First remove issue values
df2 <- df[df$x>1,]
#Train a new model
pred.fits2 <- expand.grid(x=seq(1, 2000, length=2001))
fit2 <- lm(data = df2, log(y) ~ log(x))
pm2 <- predict(fit2, newdata=pred.fits2, interval="confidence")
pred.fits2$py <- pm2[,1]
#Plot 2
ggplot(df2, aes(x=log(x), y=log(y))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, size=1.5) +
  geom_line(data=pred.fits2, aes(x=log(x), y=py), size=.2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @ Duck, thanks for the quick and clear explanation. Therefore the geom_smooth() function can sense the axes are being changed from linear to log and generates the regression line using lm() over log10(x) ~ log10(y) formula, whereas the geom_line() misses it, as it was done out of ggplot() invocation.

Comment: @Deb.M Yeah, try testing first with the models and transformations as seen in the post. Some functions in `ggplot2` manage transformations in different ways so you could be in trouble trying to replicate something that is very logical from you perspective. I hope that helped you :)

Comment: your answer allowed me to see the light, so definitely it was helpful :). One more related question. Is there a way to keep the axes as 0,1,10,100... instead of 0,1,2,3... much like plotting the graph on log-log paper?

Comment: @Deb.M I would suggest you tou use `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()`. These functions have a labels, limits and break options so that you can customize the axis. I hope that was helpful :)

Comment: @Deb.M If more help is needed let me know. Sometimes I can be unclear !